# Cuenta regresiva dependiendo las fechas de una lista

Tags: c#

Buenas, mi consulta es la siguiente tengo un windows Form como en la siguiente imagen.

[image: Reductor de Fecha a Tiempo Cero]

Lo que busco es que al darle Start. el tiempo arriba solo cuente los segundos totales para atras. Hasta llegar a cero. Será entonces cuando esa fecha se añada al List2 y el contador mostrado en el label "Fuera de Tiempo: 00" aumente su valor en 1, por otra parte el timer se reiniciará y contará los segundos totales de la siguiente fila de la list1, hará esto hasta que se terminen todas las filas de la lista. Y eso es todo.

Yo uso For para contar cada fila, pero no logro que en una fila se detenga el For hasta que se cumpla el tiempo del Timer, para que luego pase a la siguiente Fila. Esa es mi pregunta. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Se te olvidó compartir el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente no utilices un For para recorrer la lista, simplemente utiliza el Timer y cuando sea cero obtén el siguiente de la lista.

Por ejemplo:

```
int objetos = lista.count;
int posicion = 0;
public void cambiar_Posicion()
{ 
    if lista(posicion) <= timeSpawn(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        {
        if posicion < objetos
        {
            posicion++;
        }
    }
    lista(posicion).Tick += timer_tick;
    lista(posicion).Start;
}
public void timer_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //tu lógica.

    cambiar_Posicion()
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, **este código no ha sido probado, solo es para referencia**.

Comment: Interesante!.... hice un código similar y me funcionó... definitivamente el For me fue un dolor de cabeza... gracias por contestar!

Comment: Hola @Strapicarus esta pregunta me llevo a otra... talvez puedas darme una mano

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59912/problema-con-operaciones-ocultas-en-tab-page-secundarios-de-un-tab-control