# ¿Problema con operaciones ocultas en tab_page secundarios de un tab_control?

Tags: c#

Buenas, tengo una nueva pregunta, tengo 1 tab_control con 2 tab_pages, ambos tab_pages tienen un datagridview que cargan datos de MySQL, en el primero tab_page muestra un listado de clientes, y en la segunda muestra un listado de llamadas, las cuales mediante un timer(con intervalo de 1 segundo) se marcan en rojo, cuando no se les llamo en su franja programada.

Bien, el problema es que si el tab_page1 esta activo, el 2do Tab_page no sombrea en rojo las filas con horario excedido hasta que ese tab_page2 este activo, a partir de ahí recién comienza a sombrear en rojo pero se saltea las primeras filas, puede que se saltee más o menos filas, dependiendo de cuanto me demore en activar ese tab_page2, si me demoro demasiado no sombrea en rojo, ninguna.

¿Como ejecutar esos procesos en el tab_page2 para que haga el sombreado de las filas del dgw sin que necesite estar activa esa pestaña?

[image: Problema con Tab_Pages inactivos]

En este ejemplo pueden ver que solo se activaron 2 filas porque me demore 2 segundos en cambiar de tab_page1 a este tab_page

Comment: Creo que el problema que tienes es por como coloreas el datagridview. Es posible que estes haciendo un bucle por todas las filas y coloreando manualmente?

Comment: Tal vez utilizando una pila en vez de activarlas en tiempo real funcione. Cuando el tab este inactivo agregas la info a una pila y cuando sea activo utilizas la pila para actualizar el tab. Podrías compartir un poco de código? para que sea mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: En el evento Load llamo a la clase SQL para cargar todas las llamadas pendientes y las inserto en un DataTable que después irán aun DataGridView del tabPage en cuestión:

http://rextester.com/XNRZ92934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en mi comentario, creo que el problema lo tienes por colorear tu manualmente el datagrid. Lo mejor para colorear filas en un DataGridView es utilizar el evento [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx). Este evento se dispara cada vez que el grid debe pintar una celda. En tu caso, lo que yo haría sería lo siguiente:

**Constructor del formulario**

```
this.dgw_dXp.CellFormatting += 
               new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(this.dgw_dXp_CellFormatting);
```

**Manejador CellFormatting**

```
private void dgw_dXp_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan TiempoTotal = Convert.ToDateTime(dgw_dXp.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) - DateTime.Now;
    segundos = Convert.ToDouble(TiempoTotal.TotalSeconds.ToString());
    if (segundos < 1)
    { 
        dgw_dXp.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor=Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        dgw_dXp.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor=Color.White;
    }
}
```

Con esto yo creo que al cambiar de tab ya debería actualizar correctamente las filas. Como quieres que tambien se actualize cada minuto, en tu timer haces esto:

**Timer**

```
private void t_Contador_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgw_dXp.Refresh();
}
```

Creo que haciendolo de esta manera, todo te funcionará como esperas.

Comment: hice un codigo similar y me funcionó pero creo que el tuyo esta mejor, muchas gracias! :D